# sometimes Unable to resolve host sometimes connected

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an android application and the app's connection to the internet just work fine until an "Unable to resolve host" error occured in the error log. I already have "android.permission.INTERNET" on my manifest file, my Wifi Connection is already open but my app still says the unable to resolve host. I tried to close and re-open the WiFi again and it worked, but to make sure I tried a third attempt. I re-closed and re-opened my WiFi connection then the app suddenly goes back on the error 'Unable to resolve host'.

EDITED:
[Codes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9icp.png)

I tried hostname on my browser, and it works just fine.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yep0Z.png)

If the app smoothly connected before and suddenly receiving this error, what could be the problem and the possible solution?

Thank you in advance.

Apologies to my English and grammar.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: Please post your activity code here where you have applied your host name so we can check issue.

Comment: I tried this link 'http://guruapp.000webhostapp.com/index.php?mode=login&username=ann@gmail.com&password=ann' that I'm using right now, I have  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> placed already since. Reconnecting with the wifi actually solves the connection problem but after few minutes it just couldn't access the host again